# Issue in my Gps service

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, service, gps

I've been stuck on a issue since 2 or 3 weeks now, searching for every tuto or same issue on the net but i didn't find the answer of my questions.

I actually work on a Android application running with Xamarin in C#

Here is my issue :
I want to start a GPS service at the start of my application that request the coordinate every X minute (it's not relevante)

So my service look like :

```
[Service(Name = "com.xamarin.ServicesDemo2")]
public class GpsService : Service, ILocationListener
{
    static readonly string TAG = typeof(GpsService).FullName;

    private LocationManager _locationManager;
    private Location _location;

    [return: GeneratedEnum]
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "OnStartCommand");


        if (_locationManager == null)
            _locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);

        _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GpsProvider, 0, 0, this);

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "OnDestroy");
        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        _location = location;
    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
    {
    }

    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
    {
    }

    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, [GeneratedEnum] Availability status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }
}
```

And i call it in my mainActivity like this :

```
private void BtnValidateClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Intent serviceToStart = new Intent(this, typeof(GpsService));
    StartService(serviceToStart);
}
```

When i run this and put a breakpoint in the `OnLocationChanged` method, i'm never getting in there, so i suppose i did something wrong.

Here are my questions :

- How to know when the `OnLocationChanged` has been triggered ?
- How and where to indicate in the code that i want to trigger `OnLocationChanged` every X minute ?

Last thing, the reason why i want to trigger every X minute is for not over-use the battery of the device so if you have another method, i'll take it !

I apologize for my english, i tried my best...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi, have you tried it on emulator? You can trigger the event by sending location.

Comment: Hey, I wanted to close my thread because i solved this by running on an emulator ! Yes when I send location on emulator, the OnLocationChanged is triggered, that's all I needed, thanks for you answer as well, ciao !

Comment: You can provide an answer for you question, and mark it. It will help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by running on an emulator ! When I send location on emulator, the OnLocationChanged is triggered, that's all I needed.